# Can someone point me to a Java library that actually compresses files, with a notable size difference?

Tags: java, compression, zip

i have searched for different compression algorithms for java, and i finally set my mind on the the deflate algorithm that is already included in the java SDK.

When i started it worked fine with text files, but it didn't do much compression size wise with other type of files like (JPG,etc.), also there is no much difference when i change the compression level.

What i need is a library that will compress all files with a notable file size decrease.

Is what i am looking for even exists??

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you checked out `GZIPOutputStream`?

Comment: JPG is already compressed. Compressed files hardly can be compressed further, and "notable file size decrease" cannot be acheived in principle.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov I have also tried with video files and i got no compression also. Does that mean that since all (or most) standard file formats are already compressed, then it effectively only compresses text files?

Comment: @Arrem i will, but i already saw the benchmark and it didn't make a huge difference.

Comment: @M090009 most files formats for video and pictures are compressed. And those that are not (like .bmp) cannot be compressed effectively with text oriented zip or gzip algorithms - special image compressing methods should be applied.

Comment: @M090009 compression algorithms , usually finds the long patterns and decodes the patterns into other symbols ( like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding algorithm ). To know more how java does compress read http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/compress-1565076.html . gave samples . depends on the image and image resolution and variation between the pixels

Comment: If you look for better than GZIP try XZ: http://tukaani.org/xz/java.html You won't find anything with much better compression ratio for general purpose data compressor (Its based on LZMA).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You not going to get much compression out of JPG, MP3, AVI or any other binary files, they kinda do that for you already.  You can however get good compression results out of text files like JS, CSS, HTML, etc.

Comment: Thanks, yes as you and @AlexeiKaigorodov confirmed my doubts that these formats are already compressed.